# match till a pattern using re in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find a pattern between two pattern specific pattern in my case (name"=>") and (") :

```
In[78]: temp = '"name"=>"Aditya Patel  % _ . -  2015"'
In[79]: res = re.search(r'(name"=>")([\w\s\d]+)',temp)
In[80]: res.group()
Out[80]: 'name"=>"Aditya Patel  '
```

So my output should have everything in between.

In the example above it would be

```
Aditya Patel  % _ . -  2015
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
re.search(r'name"=>"([^"]*?)"',temp).group(1)
```

**output:**

```
'Aditya Patel  % _ . -  2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
print re.search(r'name"=>"([^"]+)',temp).group(1)
```

OR using lookbehind:

```
print re.search(r'(?<=name"=>")[^"]+',temp).group()
```

**Output:**

```
Aditya Patel  % _ . -  2015
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes that the quoted value you are after is the second in the input string:

```
s = '"name"=>"Aditya Patel  % _ . -  2015"'
if s.find('=>') > -1:
    print(s.split('=>')[1].strip(' "'))
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/GGIWfq)